# jQuery mobile listview outside data-role="page" wrapper

Tags: listview, jquery-mobile

How can I apply jQuery mobile listview styles to a list that reside outside the data-role="page" wrapper?

Comment: Why? the data-rold="page" wrapper is the page loaded by jqm when changing pages. Why do you put it outside? it won't be rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Put your list inside the page wrapper, after it been rendered move it were you want it.

```
$('#page').before($("#menu"));
```